# Java multithreading and linkedlist operations

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I run a java server to support an android game i am working on. The server receives a client socket, opens a new thread, read the object being sent from the client and perform operations on a linkedlist.

The operations consists of, adding the new object to the linked list if the list is empty.
If the list is not empty, the thread adds the object to the list and returns a different object in the list.

```
if (!check.getName().equals(fighter1.getName())) {
  fighter2 = check;
  itr.remove();
  OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
  oos.writeObject(fighter2);        
  oos.flush();
  checkName = false;
}
```

This is the remove part of the thread, the adding part comes a little bit before and is basically just list.add(object);

Now, the problem is since this server can run multiple threads, what happens if 10 users connect at the same time, wouldn't this have a big chance of causing the list to have null pointers/other errors.

I want to expand this server to have the ability to handle hundreds of connection of the same time, and I'm currently just testing it with a handful of alpha testers.
Got any good ideas as for how I can make the altering of data as safe as possible?

Comment: Do your add and remove need to be atomic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linked list is not thread safe, you can try other thread safe collection like [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! Ill check this out and alter my server

Answer (score 1):

I think you should simply use a thread safe List, like CopyOnWriteArrayList, as long as speed doesn't start to matter. (Its a dirty but simple way ;) )

Comment: Tbh, the data coming through to the server is not very sensitive, and should it happen that the server looses an object during the add and remove phase it is not a big deal at all, the user wont even notice. The only issue is if the list gets a nullpointer and crashes. Speed is not a huge issue, the client uses the object it recieves to start a match. i have made a loading screen so the client will wait. But it would be an issue if 100 people where conneceted and had to wait a minute to start the match.

Comment: Then I think CopyOnWriteArrayList should be the best solution for your problem. (You don't even have to change code)

Comment: So you mean just changing my linkedlist to a copyonwritearraylist?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.